Problema con archivos gdb al generar paquete
tengo este código:
df_punto_muestreo_flora = gpd.read_file(gdb_path, layer="PuntoMuestreoFlora")
df_muestreo_flora_fustal_tb = gpd.read_file(gdb_path, layer="MuestreoFloraFustalTB")
if 'VOL_TOTAL' in df_muestreo_flora_fustal_tb.columns:
    print(df_muestreo_flora_fustal_tb['VOL_TOTAL'].dtype)
else:
    print("La columna 'VOL_TOTAL' no está presente.")

print(f"df_muestreo_flora_fustal_tb.columns: {df_muestreo_flora_fustal_tb.columns}")

# Asegurarse de que ambas columnas 'ID_MUEST' estén en el mismo formato
df_muestreo_flora_fustal_tb['ID_MUEST'] = df_muestreo_flora_fustal_tb['ID_MUEST'].astype(str)
df_punto_muestreo_flora['ID_MUEST'] = df_punto_muestreo_flora['ID_MUEST'].astype(str)



if 'VOL_TOTAL' in df_muestreo_flora_fustal_tb.columns:
    # Realizar el merge entre los dos DataFrames usando 'ID_MUEST' como clave
    df_combined = df_muestreo_flora_fustal_tb[['ID_MUEST', 'VOL_TOTAL']].merge(
        df_punto_muestreo_flora[['ID_MUEST', 'N_COBERT']],
        on='ID_MUEST',
        how='inner'
    )
else:
    print("Error: 'VOL_TOTAL' no está presente en los datos.")


# # Agrupamos por 'N_COBERT' y 'ID_MUEST', sumando 'VOL_TOTAL'
df_grouped = df_combined.groupby(['N_COBERT', 'ID_MUEST']).agg({'VOL_TOTAL': 'sum'}).reset_index()

al ejecutarlo con python funciona y encuentre VOL_TOTAL, pero al empaquetarlo con pyinstaller no lo encuentra, usando los mismos archivos
